# How can I "compact" click events that use the same function?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am creating a program that will allow a user to book seats in a theatre as a college project. It will feature a series of picture boxes that the user can click on to book a seat. The image in the picture box changes between the colour red and the colour green every time its pressed (if it is green, when it is clicked, it will become red etc.)

As for the function DetermineEnable, the value SeatNo represents the seat in the array enabled. This value is specific for each box (For seat A1, the seatno is 1). This value must remain the same, for the same box. The seatserial is just the name given to each picturebox (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 etc).

I have only posted code for the first 5 seats, as this should give a general idea about what I'm asking.

What I'm asking is how can I "compact" all of the picturebox click events, So I only have to call the function "DetermineEnable" once or twice rather than 50+ times.

Many thanks!

```
' /// VISUAL AND INTERACTIVE DISPLAY
Sub DetermineEnable(ByVal SeatNo As Integer, ByVal SeatSerial As PictureBox)
    If Enabled(SeatNo) = True Then
        Enabled(SeatNo) = False
        TotalCustomers = TotalCustomers - 1
    ElseIf Enabled(SeatNo) = False Then
        Enabled(SeatNo) = True
        TotalCustomers = TotalCustomers + 1
    End If
    PictureLocation(SeatNo, SeatSerial)
    UpdateEverything()
End Sub

Function PictureLocation(ByVal SeatNo As Integer, ByVal Picturebox As PictureBox) As String
    If Enabled(SeatNo) = True Then
        PictureLocation = "C:\Users\Wallace\Desktop\Theatre_Booking_System\enabled.png"
    Else
        PictureLocation = "C:\Users\Wallace\Desktop\Theatre_Booking_System\disabled.png"
    End If
    Picturebox.ImageLocation = PictureLocation
End Function

Private Sub a1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles a1.Click
    DetermineEnable(1, a1)
End Sub
Private Sub a2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles a2.Click
    DetermineEnable(2, a2)
End Sub
Private Sub a3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles a3.Click
    DetermineEnable(3, a3)
End Sub
Private Sub a4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles a4.Click
    DetermineEnable(4, a4)
End Sub
Private Sub a5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles a5.Click
    DetermineEnable(5, a5)
End Sub
```

Comment: Are these PictureBoxes created at design-time or run-time?

Comment: The pictureboxes are created at design-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the integer in the `Tag` property. Use the same sub to handle all the click events and cast the sender back to the PictureBox - which is the PictureBox that was clicked. `a1.Tag = 1`

```
Private Sub a1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles a1.Click, a2,Click, a3.Click'etc...
   Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
   DetermineEnable(Convert.ToInt32(pb.Tag), pb)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution! Unfortunately, this method doesn't work, as a1, a2, and a3 all act as one picturebox. Clicking on a1 works as it should, however, if a1 is enabled and I click on a2 or a3, the count reduces back to 0, which shows the 3 buttons share the same value for SeatNo.

Comment: @WallaceBreen this should work for you as long as you put unique seat numbers in your tag property, the sender in your click eventhandler **is** the picturebox that originated the click.

Comment: @Mark Hall That would make sense, I was thinking picturebox.property, rather than the actual picturebox option in the designer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wouldn't this require you to manually add a Tag value to all 50+ buttons on your form?!...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes, but this also has many other uses like a more robust/stable refresh system (shows an enabled image for the corresponding/enabled pictureboxes being loaded) I have also been trying to figure out for the past couple of days.

Comment: If the value to be associated is embedded in the name then you can extract it as I've shown in my answer.  Then you don't have to go adding 50+ tags.  You just need to be clearer on the naming convention.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes you are correct, but I would rather depend on entering the Tag property than depending on the name of the control having to be in a certain format

Comment: @Idle_Mind How would you implement multiple letters in the name ("b" rather than "a")?

Answer (score 0):

Wire up the buttons in the Load() event, then extract the value from the name itself:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50 ' <-- ajdust as necessary
        matches = Me.Controls.Find("a" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then
            Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
            AddHandler PB.Click, AddressOf pb_Click
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub pb_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim PB As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim value As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(PB.Name.TrimStart("a".ToCharArray), value) Then
        DetermineEnable(value, PB)
    End If
End Sub
```

Get rid of all the old hardcoded handlers for the PictureBoxes.

Comment: For the lines that require a character(e.g. the Me.Controls.Find... line), would it be possible to use more than one character in the same line?

Comment: You can make whatever pattern you like.  Give more details and examples and I can help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work - put it in your `Form_Load()`...

```
Dim Pics = {a1, a2}

For i = 1 To Pics.Length
    Dim Pic = Pics(i - 1)
    AddHandler Pic.Click, Sub() DetermineEnable(i, Pic)
Next
```

If you don't want to define the list of controls manually, change

```
Dim Pics = {a1, a2}
```

to

```
Dim PicNamePattern As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^a[0-9]*$")
Dim Pics = Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control).
              Where(Function(x) PicNamePattern.IsMatch(x.Name))
```